# Custom ListView error when inserting many Views

Tags: android

Actually I have created a custom `ListView`. I want to add items to this custom `ListView` dynamically. But in my case, the first item is inserted without any problem but when I try to insert the second item it gives an error. If anyone knows how to solve this, please suggest it to me.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/historyFrmLstView2"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/historyFrmLstView1"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dip">
</ListView> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**ListView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="#00000000">
<TextView
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@drawable/history_scroll_title_label_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtHistoryDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewHeading"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">
</TextView>  

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
 public void displayHistory()
 {
    String strDisplay[] = {" "};
    historyFrmLstView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historyFrmLstView2);
    int iHistCount = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryCount();
    int i;
    SimpleDateFormat sdFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");

    for (i=0; i<iHistCount; i++)
    {
            strDisplay[i] = "";

            Date dtHist = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryDate(iHistCount);

            strDisplay[i]=sdFormatter.format(dtHist.getTime());

            aHistFrmAdpter2 = new HistoryFrmCustomAdapter2(this,strDisplay);
            historyFrmLstView2.setAdapter(aHistFrmAdpter2);  
    }
 }
```

**custom Adapter.java**

```
public class HistoryFrmCustomAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter
{

public String heading1[];
public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public HistoryFrmCustomAdapter2(Activity context,String[] heading1) 
{
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.heading1=heading1;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() 
{
    return heading1.length; 
}

public Object getItem(int position) 
{   
    return null;
}
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return 0;
}
public static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView txtHistoryDisplay;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.histryfrm_listview2, null);

        holder.txtHistoryDisplay =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtHistoryDisplay);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    holder.txtHistoryDisplay.setText(heading1[position]);
    return convertView;
} 
}
```

Comment: what error....is it force close??

Comment: yeh it force close error

Comment: Open command promt from android SDK platform_tools directory..  if you are using windows platform and type adb devices
your device will be there 
then type adb -s [yourdevicenamefrom abovecommand] logcat
then give that logcat here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think that may be used below code..

```
public void displayHistory()
 {
    String strDisplay[] = {" "};
    historyFrmLstView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historyFrmLstView2);
    int iHistCount = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryCount();
    int i;
    SimpleDateFormat sdFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");

    for (i=0; i<iHistCount; i++)
    {
            strDisplay[i] = "";

            Date dtHist = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getHistoryDate(iHistCount);

            strDisplay[i]=sdFormatter.format(dtHist.getTime());


    }

     aHistFrmAdpter2 = new HistoryFrmCustomAdapter2(this,strDisplay);
     historyFrmLstView2.setAdapter(aHistFrmAdpter2);  
 }
```

Comment: Actually error occur while running in the device..when i add first date it work perfectly but when i add second date it terminate..error is.."The Application has stopped unexpextedly"

Comment: hey nick its working..but with a drawbacks..actually what i do is declare String strDisplay=new String[10];but problem is it create 10 list with no item..now when i add item its add item in the list but not more than 10..if u add more than 10 it gives the same error..

Comment: Hey you can use  ArrayList<String> strDisplay instead of String strDisplay[]. so you can add any number of item.

Comment: have you check i have comment above?

Comment: @Anshuman let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1182/discussion-between-nik-and-anshuman)

Answer (score 0):

there will be only one element in your string array strDisplay[iHistCount]. since you r putting value at the last position each time. replace iHistCount with i.